# iOS - Question about Memory management : NSArray case

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray

I have this code:

```
- (void) firstMethod{
NSString *first = @"Hello";
NSString *second = @"World";
NSArray *myFirstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: first, second, nil];
[mySecondArray addObject :myFirstArray];
[myFirstArray release];
}
```

when I do release of myFirstArray, can I lose my two string? or they remain stored in mySecondArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and second have a retain count of 1 (made autorelease) when creating the objects.
Each object added to an array has it's retain count raised.

So when adding first and second to firstArray, their retain count is raised to 2 (with 1 of autorelease).
When adding these objects from firstArray to secondArray, nothing happens with firstArray, but first and second are found into firstArray and added again into secondArray, so their retain count is again raised, to 3 (including 1 of autorelease).

If you release first Array, its own retain count is decreased, and each object it "contains" has its retain count decreased too. So the array has its retain count at 0 and is deleted from memory. First and second have their retain count decreased to 2 (including 1 of autorelease).

If you wait some time, the autorelease effects is triggered, and first and second have their retain count decreased by 1, so they have a retain count of 1, the one that has been set when adding first and second from firstArray into secondArray.

Just keep in memory that the array does not contain any object but references (pointers if you prefer) to objects that are outside the array.

if you write :

```
NSArray *myFirstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"test1", nil];
```

it creates a string object, put test1 into it, put its retain count at 1, and make it autorelease. Then the memory address of the object is inserted into the array, that has also it's own retain count set to 1.

Said in another way, myFirstArray is a pointer to an array of pointers, where each object has its own retain count.

**EDIT** : the desciption given is for addObjectsFromArray:
I've read again the question and I see that the question is for addObject:

So the receipe is the same. Let's say that the Retain Count is in parenthesis and AR means autorelease :

```
NSString *first = @"Hello";
NSString *second = @"World";
```

first (1 AR)
second (1 AR)

```
NSArray *myFirstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: first, second, nil];
```

myFirstArray (1)
first (1 AR + 1)
second (1 AR + 1)

```
[mySecondArray addObject :myFirstArray];
```

mySecondArray (1 AR, assuming it's created with [NSMutableArray array]; that is missing)
myFirstArray (1 + 1) retained by the call
first (1 AR + 1) no change
second (1 AR + 1) no change

```
[myFirstArray release];
```

mySecondArray (1 AR) no change
myFirstArray (1) -1, but still living
first (1 AR + 1) no change
second (1 AR + 1) no change

Hope that's clear :-)

**Let's imagine You wait some time.**

- The autorelease of mySecondArray is triggered :
  mySecondArray (0) KILL
- then myFirstArray receive a release
  myFirstArray  (0) KILL
- then each object into myFirstArray receive a release
  first (1 AR) -1, but still living a short time
  second (1 AR) -1, but still living a short time
- Wait some time for the next event loop, then the autorelease of the strings are triggered :
  first (0) KILL
  second (0) KILL

Answer (score 1):

They aren't stored by the second array, but your first array will be retained by the second array.

Meaning, when you call release on the first array, it won't be released until the array is removed from the second array.

Second array retains the first array.
The first array retains the strings.

Comment: then if I don't release mySecondArray the string are stored inside mySecondArray? right?

Comment: Not entirely.  They remain retained (owned) by the first array.  You never actually added the __objects themselves__ to the second array.  You only added the myFirstArray (called via `addObject:`) to the second array.  Therefore, second array owns first; first array owns the items.  Were you confusing `addObject:` with `addObjectsFromArray:`?  One adds the object itself to the receiver, the second adds the objects of the array to the receiver.